# AR(n) process error variance in R

Tags: r, time-series, variance, arima, autoregressive

I was wondering where does the "sigma^2 estimated as 12.2" in the following example came from. I tried to compute by myself the variance of the residuals, however it seems I probably forgot something. Can you point out what am I missing?

```
x=c(-2.6779495241255313, -1.2934144511034473, -0.2780248054025196, 0.7111655218852636, -7.20035657196907)
y=arima(x, include.mean = F, order = c(1,0,0))
y
var(residuals(y))/(5-1)*5
```

Comment: Welcome to CV, Beppe. Could you please check `?arima` and see if the output helps you to get closer to the answer?

Answer (score 4):

It's using the mean square error:

```r
mean(residuals(y)^2)
```

There is no need to substract the mean, as it is 0 for residuals.

If you used `forecast::Arima` rather than `stats:arima`, then the `sigma2` estimate uses the residual df rather than the number of observations in the denominator:

```r
sum(residuals(y)^2 / 4)
```